# Cache on android Libraries

Tags: android, caching, android-resources, android-context

I'm writing an Android Library, that will be used in several applications.

How can I find the [External Cache Dir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29) for libraries. As I know, libraries doesn't have how to get the context application.

Answer (score 0):

Have the application that is hosting your library pass in a `File` object for where they want your cache files stored.

Or, have the application that is hosting your library pass in a `Context` object, from which you can call `getCacheDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`.

A library does not have a cache directory. Applications have cache directories.

Comment: And how can I access the context from anywhere?

Comment: @Victor: Since I have no idea how you have constructed your library, I cannot answer that. Ideally, you don't hold onto the `Context` for more than a few microseconds, long enough to call `getCacheDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`. You can then store that `File` object wherever it makes sense for your library, including a static data member. If you do feel that you need to hold onto some `Context` for a long time, call `getApplicationContext()` on the passed-in `Context` and hold onto that, so you do not leak memory.

Comment: I'm making a library for a legacy c++ code. So there is many places that I need to get cache folder, but I don't have java environment.

Comment: @Victor: All the more reason to hold onto the `File` object, or the results of calling `getAbsolutePath()` on the `File` object, to get a `String` representation of the path that the C++ code can use.